# Не могу получить объект из json

Tags: javascript, json, объекты

Есть такой файл `json`:

```
{
  "rpe":{
    "2020": {
      "4": {
        "18": [
          { "name": "Проезд", "value": 5, "scratch": "Проезд" },
          { "name": "Питание", "value": 10, "scratch": "Питание" },
          { "name": "Коммуналка", "value": 20, "scratch": "Еще" }
        ],
        "19": [
          { "name": "Проезд", "value": 10, "scratch": "Поездка на такси" },
          { "name": "Питание", "value": 20, "scratch": "ресторан" },
          { "name": "Еще", "value": 30, "scratch": "досуг" },
          { "name": "Еще_2", "value": 30, "scratch": "досуг" }
        ]
      },
      "5": {
        "1": [
          { "name": "Проезд", "value": 5, "scratch": "Проезд" },
          { "name": "Питание", "value": 10, "scratch": "Питание" },
          { "name": "Коммуналка", "value": 20, "scratch": "Еще" }
        ],
        "2": [
          { "name": "Проезд", "value": 10, "scratch": "Поездка на такси" },
          { "name": "Питание", "value": 20, "scratch": "ресторан" },
          { "name": "Еще", "value": 30, "scratch": "досуг" },
          { "name": "Еще_2", "value": 30, "scratch": "досуг" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Я его забираю таким способом:

```
async function getDay(method, url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const today = await response.json();
  return today;
}

const todayLocal = getDay("GET", path);
```

В консоли это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Т.е. в консоли я вижу все его данные, но в `js` получить к ним доступ не могу. Например `todayLocal.rpe` выдает `undefinined`.

Помогите пожалуйста получить полноценный объект.

Answer (score 3):

Асинхронная функція `getDay` возвращает промис - значит нужно `await`.
(Смотрите на последнюю строчку)

```
async function getDay(method, url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const today = await response.json();
  return today;
}

const todayLocal = await getDay("GET", path);
```

Comment: я не спорю но у него и так этот код  один в один -

Comment: Нет. Последняя строка=)

Comment: точно ...вот я очкарик ..сорри